# How to find Twitch username from a user ID?

Tags: web-scraping, twitch, twitch-api

I am trying to find a twitch username from its ID? How do I do that?

For example, if I have the twitch user https://www.twitch.tv/user, I can open up the API https://api.ivr.fi/twitch/resolve/user, and find the users "id":"12345678". But how can I out from an user id, identify the user or username?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the twtich API, you can register an app in the Developer portal, the use this code to get the channel name:

```
import requests
import json

CHANNEL_ID = '51496027'

#https://dev.twitch.tv/console/apps/create
client_id = '**client_id_here**'
client_secret = '**client_secret_here**'
grant_type = 'client_credentials'

# Get access token using app authentication exchange
url = 'https://id.twitch.tv/oauth2/token'
payload = {
    'client_id': client_id,
    'client_secret': client_secret,
    'grant_type': grant_type,
}
response = requests.post(url, data=payload)
access_token = json.loads(response.text)['access_token']

# Set up headers with access token for API requests
headers = {
    'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}',
    'Client-Id': client_id,
}

# Make API requests
url = f'https://api.twitch.tv/helix/channels?broadcaster_id={CHANNEL_ID}'

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
data = json.loads(response.text)
print(data['data'][0]['broadcaster_name'])
```